# How to create smooth animation for progressBar in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying make smooth animation for progressView increment. I am developing for iOS5. This is my code so far.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{        
     [energyProgress setProgress:0.72 animated:YES];
}
```

This animation is not working properly. energyProgress is defined as UIProgressView. Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean working properly? Is there no animation or is there no change at all?

Comment: there is just quick moving of the slider. It doesn't look like an animation

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these open-source controls, they may help you:

- [ADVProgressBar for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/advprogressbar)
- [AJProgressPanel for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ajprogresspanel)
- [DDProgressView for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ddprogressview)
- [PDColoredProgressview for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/pdcoloredprogressview)

Comment: I know that it can be done with UIProgressView, and I would like to search for that solution. But thanks for the controls